# paint unicode java

Tags: java

I got stuck in java at the paint method. Printing out special letters with `System.out` will work but not if I'm trying to paint it with `g.drawString()`.

This will work:

```
System.out.println("\u2197");
```

This will not:

```
g.drawString("\u2197", 20, 20);
```

I'm getting only rectangles on my screen but not the sign.

Comment: Nice point out by WernerVesterås. @uuser2035598 Are you able to draw other Strings ? watch here for more information about the Fonts that Do not support "\u2197" String: http://www.htmlescape.net/21/unicode_char_2197.html

Answer (score 5):

You should use a font which have the symbols you are trying to display.